# Do whales in ocean use hyperbolic geometry to communicate?

Tags: acoustics

Since the *speed of sound increases with depth* in an ocean, the shortest time for the sound to travel between points $A$ and $B$ *may* be a curved path. But does sound actually take this curved path ? I mean if the whale at point $A$ makes a sound, intuition tells me it should go **straight** to point $B$(shortest distance.) Why would the sound go in a curve so that it reaches the point $B$ in **shortest amount of time** ?

[image]

Comment: The body of the question and the title seem to bear no relation. Also, what exactly do you mean when you say _"it should go straight to point B"_? In particular, what basic principles or axioms is the "should" predicated on? It seems unclear what particular physics concept you want to ask about. Voting to close.

Comment: @DvijMankad By straight I'm referring to an euclid straight line, which I feel is reasonable to expect because that's what happens in general when we speak in air with uniform density. The shortest distance path is also the shortest time path. Don't you think so ?

Comment: As I mentioned, my question is about ''should'' in "it **should** go straight to point B". As I already wrote, what basic principles or axioms is the ''should'' predicated on?

Comment: I guess the basic principle is that sound and light normally  travel in straight lines radially out from their sources ?

Comment: @DvijMankad Does that satisfy you or do you want me to edit the question and explain a bit more so that it helps others understand easily ?

Comment: Ok, a little bit clearer. But I still don't get what any of this has to do anything with hyperbolic geometry. Apart from that, to partially respond to what your question seems to be--the straight line rule for sound signals is valid only when the medium is homogeneous. As you already point out yourself, the sound signals would bend in an inhomogeneous medium (i.e., refract) where the refraction pattern can be deduced via extremizing the travel-time. So, in my view, you already seem to have resolved what you seem to ask.

Comment: @DvijMankad The whale diagram I attached is the [poincare half plane model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) for hyperbolic geometry. Also I know about light refraction but never heard about sound refraction. My physics is a bit rusty, not as good as math. Kindly pardon if these seem trivial.. Let me google a bit and get back :)

Comment: Thanks for your clarification but I still don't get how the hyperbolic geometry enters the picture. If the question is simply whether the sound rays would bend or not in an inhomogeneous medium then the answer is yes and the answer to the question what decides the specifics of the bent curve is the extremization principle. I don't see how hyperbolic geometry enters this discussion so far.

Comment: I've a textbook on non euclid geometries in which it says whales do use hyperbolic geometry, but I couldn't understand its explanation. If you have time, I can take a picture and attach here ? Thank you for being here :)

Comment: Here it is 

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/the-universe-in/9780691160160/24ch15.xhtml

Comment: The link is paywalled. I can't access the content. It would be better if you could clarify the connection of your present body of the question to the hyperbolic geometry. As it stands, it is not clear how any of it is related to hyperbolic geometry. Thanks.

Comment: @DvijMankad the whale problem is a model of hyperbolic geometry. Do you want me to list the hyperbolic geometry axioms here and show how the whale problem satisfies them ?

Comment: Perhaps this should make more sense to you than me @DvijMankad

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2dEM.png

Comment: I don't know the answer to your whale question but I totally agree with the reference to hyperbolic geometry here. Anti de sitter space models are used in the study of quantum gravity which are hyperbolic (that is have constant negative curvature). In those models particles travelling from one boundary point to another boundary point seek out the shortest path within the interior just like your whales here.

Comment: The hyperbolic path only occurs for a very specific dependence of velocity as a function of depth, so it’s not given the propagation will be hyperbolic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound *rays* are refracted and reflected in non-homogeneous media the same as light rays.

You can use *the snell law* to trace any ray path originating from $a$ (at any initial direction). For example, you can slice the ocean depth to many slices of depth $dy$ and calculate the outgoing angle as a function of incoming angle for each slice.

Eventually, only one ray from $a$ will arrive at $b$. This will be a curved ray, the curve as dictated by *snell*. It can be proven that this specific ray features the least time of travel when compared with "artificial" rays such as a straight line from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: Oh if I understand correctly, sound also continuously refracts as it travels down because the pressure is uniformly changing. This continuous refraction manifests as sound taking a curve when going from A to B. Also this curve happens to be the shortest time path ?

Comment: Yes. I would prefer *"can be proven to be..."* rather than *"happens to be..."*.

Answer (score 1):

There is more to it than just depth. Speed of sound depends on pressure, temperature, and to a small degree salinity. Salinity typically has a small effect in the ocean because it is pretty much constant. Sound travels faster at higher pressure and higher temperature.

Consider sound traveling through water of uniform temperature parallel to the bottom. The deepest part of the wave gets ahead. This angles the wave upward. Near the surface, the ocean is warmer. The means sound near the surface gets angled down. The net effect is to create a sound channel at middle depth.

Low frequency sound is absorbed very little in the ocean. It is absorbed when it hits something. But in the sound channel, it doesn't hit anything. It can travel across the entire ocean.

This sound channel is used for acoustic thermometry. A transmitter on one side of the ocean emits a signal that is received on the other side. From the time it takes to cross the ocean, you can get a good average temperature of the water in between. With multiple receivers, you can get a good average of the entire ocean.

http://atoc.ucsd.edu/

With enough paths through a body of water, you can do acoustic tomography. This is analogous to the X-ray tomography done to image the human body in a CAT scan.

https://dosits.org/people-and-sound/research-ocean-physics/how-is-sound-used-to-measure-temperature-in-the-ocean/